# Indenting a string output in a table form in bash

Tags: string, bash, format

I'm trying to output several strings somehow so the second column stays indented even if, for example the terminal is too small and has to continue on a another line.
Right now my code looks like this:

```
echo " --show=[name]     Show all packages, including"\
                         "their version."
echo "                   Date format: dd.mm.yy"
echo " --upgrade [pkg]   Upgrade packages inside"\
                         "current instance."

     #Size of terminal with output
     +--------------------------------------------+
     | --show=[name]    Show all packages, includi|
     |ng their version.                           |
     |                  Date format: dd.mm.yy     |
     | --upgrade [pkg]  Upgrade packages inside cu|
     |rrent instance.                             |
     +--------------------------------------------+
```

It cuts the text and throws it onto the beginning of the next line without any indentation. I tried using tabs but that didn't change anything.

I'm trying to get the output to adjust to any terminal size so it would look like...

```
     +--------------------------------------------+
     | --show=[name]    Show all packages,        |
     |                  including their version.  |
     |                  Date format: dd.mm.yy     |
     | --upgrade [pkg]  Upgrade packages inside   |
     |                  current instance.         |
     +--------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traditional way to do this would be the `tbl` utility used with the `troff` text formatting system, but these days I find it easier to use HTML with a text-mode browser as a renderer. However, all renderers have their own quirks, so you may need to do some work-arounds.

`w3m` does a pretty good job of rendering but it doesn't seem to correctly handle the `col` element and it doesn't handle CSS, which means you need to specify the column width on the `td` element of the first row and the vertical alignment on every `td` element. That's a bit tedious, so I do it below using variable interpolation.

Note that the width attribute's value is in *pixels*; `w3m` defaults to 8 pixels per character, so to make a column 15 characters wide, you need to specify `width=120`.

With that introduction, here is your table:

```
C1="<tr><td width=120 valign=top>" C="<td valign=top>"
w3m -dump -T text/html -cols 45 <<EOT
<table>
${C1}--show=[name]
  ${C}Show all packages, including their version.<br />
      Date format: dd.mm.yy
${C1}--upgrade [pkg]
  ${C}Upgrade packages inside current instance.
</table>
EOT
```

and the output

```
--show=[name]     Show all packages,
                  including their version.
                  Date format: dd.mm.yy
--upgrade [pkg]   Upgrade packages inside
                  current instance.
```

Changing `-cols 45` to `-cols 80`:

```
--show=[name]     Show all packages, including their version.
                  Date format: dd.mm.yy
--upgrade [pkg]   Upgrade packages inside current instance.
```

Just for fun, adding a border by changing `<table>` to `<table border>`:

```
┌─────────────────┬────────────────────────┐
│--show=[name]    │Show all packages,      │
│                 │including their version.│
│                 │Date format: dd.mm.yy   │
├─────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│--upgrade [pkg]  │Upgrade packages inside │
│                 │current instance.       │
└─────────────────┴────────────────────────┘
```

You could also try any of the other text-mode browsers, such as `lynx` and `elinks`.

Answer (score -1):

Bad news... the `echo` function I bash shell sometimes swallows blanks (specially when you split the input into several lines). You may try using the `-e` option that forces proper handling of escape characters (your `\') or, better in my opinion, split the line in a controlled way so your code would look as follows:

```
echo " --show=[name]     Show all packages, including"
echo "                   their version."
echo "                   Date format: dd.mm.yy"
echo " --upgrade [pkg]   Upgrade packages inside"
echo "                   current instance."
```

This is what I normally do and it works perfect for me.